# I am slightly confused on how oauth2 works, is this the correct flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, netflix-zuul

A client wishes to access a service. I am using a zuul gateway.
Zuul redirects to a authorization server
The client passes a user ,and password, which the authorization server uses to extract a client Id and Client secret from a repo to generate the token

The authorization server passes the token back which the zuul service will pass to each service the client wishes to access, and the service the client wishes to access authenticates each time that the token is valid.

Comment: Thats not Oauth,   you should not be passing a login and password.  and that should not result in a client id and client secret.   Try this [How Oauth2 words](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)  It uses Googles oauth server to explain it but it should be the same for any oauth server.